# How to capture OnKeyDown in TEdgeBrowser

Tags: delphi, c++builder, onkeydown, tedgebrowser

I am aware of the technique of adding injecting `onkeydown` JavaScript event into the HTML and using web message to return the code back:

```
EdgeBrowser.ExecuteScript("window.onkeydown = function(ev) { window.chrome.webview.postMessage(ev.keyCode); };");
```

And later in `TEdgeBrowser` `OnWebMessageReceived` event fetching the code from `Args` parameter.

```
procedure TfrmMain.EdgeBrowserWebMessageReceived(Sender: TCustomEdgeBrowser; Args: TWebMessageReceivedEventArgs);
begin
  // parse received WebMessage
end;
```

The problem is though `SettingsInterface.Set_IsScriptEnabled` is set to `false`, JavaScript events stop working as well.

Is there a way to capture keyboard events in `TEdgeBrowser` without the use of JavaScript and the above technique?

I also tried:

- `OnKeyDown` event of the TForm, with `KeyPreview` set to true. No effect
- ApplicationEvents - `OnMessage` `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` - no effect either.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [WebView4Delphi](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi) instead and try the [WindowlessBrowser](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi/tree/main/demos/Delphi_VCL/WindowlessBrowser) demo.
It uses the Windowless mode in WebView2 and you can intercept WM_KEY* messages with a simple [TApplicationEvents](https://github.com/salvadordf/WebView4Delphi/blob/eafc619b67a582261eff7fe6bbe258dea0eeba94/demos/Delphi_VCL/WindowlessBrowser/uWindowlessBrowser.pas#L90).

That mode uses the DirectComposition API which is not supported by Delphi but you can use the [MfPack](https://github.com/FactoryXCode/MfPack) component.

That demo is almost a direct translation of the code in the official [WebView2APISample](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/master/SampleApps/WebView2APISample) available at the WebView2Samples repository.

Comment: Thank you, it is valid alternative to TEdgeBrowser, but the windowless (visual hosting) is not really what I am looking for. It doesn't work on Windows 7 or 8, and requires me to handle all mouse/key/drag events and forward them to WebView2 control, which not the pit hole I want to explore.